# Chart.js change legend toggle behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have a radar chart from chart.js. Currently it loads in all the data which works great and the supporting legend behaves by clicking on the legend label which toggles off the data associated to the legend able. I want to be able to click on the legend label, it then toggles all the other off and maybe introduce an 'all' option? Is this doable with chart.js?

Here is how my chart looks now:

```
var chartata = { 
labels: [ 
"Strategic Development and Ownership", 
"Driving change through others", 
"Exec Disposition", 
"Commercial Acumen", 
"Develops High Performance Teams", 
"Innovation and risk taking", 
"Global Leadership", 
"Industry Leader" 
]}; 

var ctx = $("#allRadarData"); 

var config = { 
    type: 'radar', 
    data: chartata,     
    animationEasing: 'linear',
        options: {           
         legend: {
            fontSize: 10,
            display: true,
            itemWidth: 150,
            position: 'bottom',
            fullWidth: true,
            labels: {
                fontColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
                boxWidth: 10,
                padding: 20
            },
        },
         tooltips: {
            enabled: true
        },
        scale: {
            ticks: {
                fontSize: 15,
                beginAtZero: true,
                stepSize: 1,
                max: 5
            }
        } 

    },
}, 

LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, config); 

var colorArray = [

    ["#f44336", false],
    ["#E91E63", false],
    ["#9C27B0", false],
    ["#673AB7", false],
    ['#3F51B5', false],
    ["#607D8B", false]
];


for (var i in data) { 
    tmpscore=[]; 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score1); 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score2); 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score3); 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score4); 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score5); 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score6); 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score7); 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score8); 

    var color, done = false;
    while (!done) {
        var test = colorArray[parseInt(Math.random() * 10)];
        if (!test[1]) {
            color = test[0];
            colorArray[colorArray.indexOf(test)][1] = true;
            done = !done;
        }
    }


newDataset = { 
    label: data[i].firstName+' '+data[i].lastName, 
     borderColor: color,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)", 
    data: tmpscore, 
}; 

config.data.datasets.push(newDataset); 

} 

LineGraph.update(); 
},  
}); 

});
```

Comment: Show all function? pls give the idea to show all lables

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To reverse how legend label clicking behaves, you can use the legend `onClick` option to implement the new click logic.  Here is an example below that will give you the desired behavior.  Note, in this implementation if you click an already hidden label, it will unhide it, and hide all the others.

```
function(e, legendItem) {
  var index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
  var ci = this.chart;
  var alreadyHidden = (ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden === null) ? false : ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden;

  ci.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
    var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(i);

    if (i !== index) {
      if (!alreadyHidden) {
        meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !meta.hidden : null;
      } else if (meta.hidden === null) {
        meta.hidden = true;
      }
    } else if (i === index) {
      meta.hidden = null;
    }
  });

  ci.update();
};
```

Here is a [working example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/BWKKKo) as well.

If however, you want a more complex logic that will unhide a label that is currently hidden when at least one other label is currently visible, then you can use the below implementation.

```
function(e, legendItem) {
  var index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
  var ci = this.chart;
  var alreadyHidden = (ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden === null) ? false : ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden;       
  var anyOthersAlreadyHidden = false;
  var allOthersHidden = true;

  // figure out the current state of the labels
  ci.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
    var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(i);

    if (i !== index) {
      if (meta.hidden) {
        anyOthersAlreadyHidden = true;
      } else {
        allOthersHidden = false;
      }
    }
  });

  // if the label we clicked is already hidden 
  // then we now want to unhide (with any others already unhidden)
  if (alreadyHidden) {
    ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden = null;
  } else { 
    // otherwise, lets figure out how to toggle visibility based upon the current state
    ci.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
      var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(i);

      if (i !== index) {
        // handles logic when we click on visible hidden label and there is currently at least
        // one other label that is visible and at least one other label already hidden
        // (we want to keep those already hidden still hidden)
        if (anyOthersAlreadyHidden && !allOthersHidden) {
          meta.hidden = true;
        } else {
          // toggle visibility
          meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !meta.hidden : null;
        }
      } else {
        meta.hidden = null;
      }
    });
  }

  ci.update();
}
```

Here is a [working example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/QpNoYJ) for this alternate implementation as well.

To use this in your specific code, just place it in your chart's legend config using the `onClick` property.

```
var config = { 
  type: 'radar', 
  data: chartata,   
  animationEasing: 'linear',
    options: {       
     legend: {
      fontSize: 10,
      display: true,
      itemWidth: 150,
      position: 'bottom',
      fullWidth: true,
      labels: {
        fontColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
        boxWidth: 10,
        padding: 20
      },
      onClick: function(e, legendItem) {
        var index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
        var ci = this.chart;
        var alreadyHidden = (ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden === null) ? false : ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden;

        ci.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
          var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(i);

          if (i !== index) {
            if (!alreadyHidden) {
              meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !meta.hidden : null;
            } else if (meta.hidden === null) {
              meta.hidden = true;
            }
          } else if (i === index) {
            meta.hidden = null;
          }
        });

        ci.update();
      },
    },
     tooltips: {
      enabled: true
    },
    scale: {
      ticks: {
        fontSize: 15,
        beginAtZero: true,
        stepSize: 1,
        max: 5
      }
    }
  },
},
```

It was not clear what behavior you wanted the 'all' option to have, but you *might* be able to use the `legend.labels.generateLabels` option to trick Chart.js to add an 'all' label (you will have to modify the above `onClick` logic to deal with that thought.

However, I think a better solution would be to implement your own link or button outside of the chart.js canvas that would show/hide all datasets.  Check out the [Chart.js radar sample page](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/radar/radar.html) to see how they bind buttons with chart actions.

Comment: Thank you firstly for a well explained answer. I can see you understood my needs. The only thing I would need from this example is for when you select a label it removes all the other and only shows the label selected, if you then go on to click another label it adds that instead of removing the original clicked one and replacing it with the new one clicked. I am fairly new to sing chart.js so its a little confusing.

Comment: Ah, OK...I wasn't sure how you wanted to deal with that. I'll update my answer when I get to a computer later.

Comment: Ah brill thanks. Could you show in relation to my code above?

Comment: And this will work with the code I supplied in my question?

Comment: Yup, just place this into your chart's legend config using the `onClick` property.  I'll update this in my answer

Comment: Hey, I included this into my code, however it does pretty much what we discussed however when you start clicking on the labels in the legend it just hides all the others instead of building them back up?

Comment: @PhpDude I'm not sure I follow, per your requirements, when you click on a legend label all others are hidden.  From here, if you click on the same legend label then the reverse action is taken (all the previously hidden items are shown).  If you click on a hidden label then it will unhide it (assuming there is already another unhidden label) otherwise it will hide all others.  Honestly, the behavior that you wanted (that my example implements) is **quite** confusing. Perhaps you are getting confused because of this?

Comment: So yeah the behaviour was in the example you sent me on the codepen was perfect. However when I implemented it into my code it didn't behave exactly like your demonstration. When you click on a label it hides all other, when you click on the same label it shows all, but if you click on a label and then a different label it hies the original one and unhides the new one.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you implemented my 1st example (instead of the 2nd example)?  Double check that you `onClick` matches the 2nd codepen in the answer.

Comment: Working with a doughnut type chart, and getting the legendItem `undefined`.

Comment: Great explanation man! Is there any way, instead of completely hiding the other lines, we can just blur or lighten them?

Comment: Doubleclick is possible ?

Comment: Doubleclick is possible?   + 1

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code for pie chart for a single dataset to toggle the behavior of the pie chart of chart.js .

```
onClick:function(e, legendItem){
                var index = legendItem.index;
                var ci = this.chart;
                var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(0);
                var CurrentalreadyHidden = (meta.data[index].hidden==null) ? false : (meta.data[index].hidden);
                var allShown=true;
                $.each(meta.data,function(ind0,val0){
                    if(meta.data[ind0].hidden){
                        allShown=false;
                        return false; 
                    }else{
                        allShown=true;
                    }
                });
                if(allShown){
                    $.each(meta.data,function(ind,val){
                        if(meta.data[ind]._index===index){
                            meta.data[ind].hidden=false;
                        }else{
                            meta.data[ind].hidden=true;
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    if(CurrentalreadyHidden){
                        $.each(meta.data,function(ind,val){
                            if(meta.data[ind]._index===index){
                                meta.data[ind].hidden=false;
                            }else{
                                meta.data[ind].hidden=true;
                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        $.each(meta.data,function(ind,val){
                            meta.data[ind].hidden=false;
                        }); 
                     }
                 }
                ci.update();

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

a shorter code with the `legend.onClick` solution

```js
// this.chart.options
legend: {
    onClick: (_, item: LegendItem) => {
        if (!this.chart) {
            return;
        }
        const currentHidden: boolean = this.chart.data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].hidden ?? false;
        if (currentHidden) {
            this.chart.data.datasets.forEach(ds => {
                ds.hidden = true;
            });
            this.chart.data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].hidden = false;
        } else {
            this.chart.data.datasets.forEach(ds => {
                ds.hidden = currentHidden == (ds.hidden ?? false);
            });
            this.chart.data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].hidden = false;
        }
        this.chart?.update();
    },
},
```